# Use json-server to mock tests with Jest on Travis

Tags: jestjs, travis-ci, json-server

My vuejs front-end makes API calls using Axios.

I'm making unit tests and integration tests with Jest. I use axios-mock-adapter to mock API, but I need to mock every endpoint.

To make it easier, I'd like to use json-server. On a development machine, there is no problem : I launch json-server, then I launch Jest tests.

My question is about Travis CI:

- How do I launch json-server?
- How can I be sure to have an available port
- How/when do I stop json-server?

Comment: `.travis.yml` write your script in there or edit your `build` to run test in your `package.json`